# Shell script - Find and copy a string in text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a json file:

```
[{"outputType":{"type":"APK"},"apkInfo":{"type":"MAIN","splits":[],"versionCode":1},"path":"app-debug.apk","properties":{"packageId":"com.abc.def","split":"","minSdkVersion":"17"}}]
```

I want to use shell script to find the packageID (com.abc.def in this case) and copy it to a variable.
I don't really care about how it's done, as long as I get a variable holding the string, that will be perfect.

I don't do much shell script, but this task requires me to use shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v=$(sed -r 's/.*"packageId":"([^"]+)".*/\1/' file.json)
```

Look for the key "packageId" with colon and quotes, grab anything which is not a quote, followed by the quote. \1 is a reference to the matched expression in round parens.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like **jq** to process JSON and don't rely on shell script ugly hacks.

In your case it would be: `jq -r '.[0].properties.packageId'`

It's easier, more readable and safer to use tools that parse JSON.

Comment: looks like I need to install jq. I prefer not to, a hack like the accepted answer is quite sufficient for me